# Is there an instrument that can measure thickness of an object through strain?

Tags: measurements, manufacturing-engineering

So basically, I am doing a project to design a measurement tool for measuring the different layers of the quartz crucible used in the semiconductor industry. Since the crucibles undergo some deformation through the fabrication process, I was thinking if there is any technology that makes use of the degree of strain to measure the crucible layers. Could UV rays be used for the measurement with a small fragment of the deformed crucible?

Comment: Polariscope and photoelasticity are two words you should a **thorough** search on.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, I've searched the terms, but the technology only allows the determination of strain, not the measurement of the thickness of the crucible.
Thanks nonetheless for the help!